# How to satisfied this condition?

Tags: javascript, object, equality

```
let obj = {
  a: 1,
};


if (obj.a === 1 && obj.a === 2 && obj.a === 3) {
  console.log('work');
}
```

I tried to use defineProperty but It seems bad solution.

```
let obj ={} 
let i = 1  
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'a', {  
  get: function () {  
  return i++;  
 }  
});  

if(obj.a === 1 && obj.a === 2 && obj.a === 3) {  
console.log('work')  
}
```

I found solution without strict equality but it isn't fit

It's my first question in this community...

Comment: This condition will never be TRUE. Because a value can't be 1, 2 AND 3 at the same time. Maybe you're looking for the OR operator? obj.a === 1 || obj.a === 2 || obj.a === 3

Comment: a variable cannot have 3 different values ​​at the same time. Computers don't understand absurd logic

Comment: What are you trying to do actually?

Comment: @Aleksandrus It can be true if they use `defineProperty` to define `a`. A pretty ridiculous exercise, but it works as a brain teaser.

Comment: Using a getter like so: `let obj = { _a: 1, get a() { return this._a++; } };`